# CakePHP hidden _method POST

Tags: html, cakephp

When using the FormHelper->create(...), the HTML that gets rendered looks like this:

```
<form action="/blogs/add" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div style="display:none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
    </div>

    <!-- omitted: form inputs -->
</form>
```

Why is that div with the display:none; style there? How do I make it not show up?

UPDATE: Just to be clear, I'm wondering why both the div AND the hidden input inside the div show up. They don't seem to be necessary, and therefore I don't want them to be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div is there to be valid HTML.

> Non-block-level elements (such as `<input>`) are not valid directly inside `<form>` tags until HTML5. [Source](http://w3fools.com/#html_forms)

Edit: To answer your question, you can't easily get rid of it. It's hard-coded into FormHelper::create(), you'd have to override that method in a custom helper. Why is it bothering you anyways?

Comment: Well, I am using HTML5, but my question is referring to the div element AND the input inside of it. Why is the div there, why is that hidden input there? It's not 'bothering' me, I just want to understand the framework that I'm using better.

Comment: Well, if you use security component, more obvious necessary fields will be added for csrf checks and such in that div. That input, as far as I can tell, is to differentiate between add (Create) and edit (Update) forms.

Comment: add posts to the 'add' action, edit posts to the 'edit' action, why would I need a hidden input?

Comment: Say you have different names for the actions, FormHelper needs to know if its Create or Update forms and does stuff like required on update only validation rules (not 100% sure its only or exactly for this)

Comment: Meh. If that's the case, not too sure I like that. But probably not worth fighting if that's the cakephp way.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming to this recently, there is a simple solution to this now that doesn't involve a custom helper.  Using the [FormHelper templates](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses), the block of code in question is generated by the 'hiddenBlock' template.  (See the full list of default templates here: https://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.View.Helper.FormHelper.html#%24_defaultConfig).

So, to amend the example given in CakePHP's documentation to match this case and remove the wrapping `<div>` around the hidden `<input>` for _method (assuming HTML5):

```
// In your View class
$this->loadHelper( 'Form' , [ 'templates' => 'app_form' ] );


// in config/app_form.php
return [
    'hiddenBlock' => '{{ content }}'
];
```

I was confronted with this problem because I recently implemented a Content Security Policy that doesn't allow inline styling, and I thought I should share my working solution.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-forms) might help you.

Whenever you use FormHelper->create() method ,A hidden input field is generated to override the default HTTP method. You can also change it by passing [type option](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options-for-create). Kindly ask if it not worked for you.

Comment: I will try this later, but I'm not overriding anything. Note the form method attribute is already 'post'.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
'inputDefaults' => array(
    'div' => false
   )
));
```

The divs won't be created on any input of the form.

Answer (score -1):

use hiddenField => false property

Comment: This doesn't stop the output of that div